# How to evolve an expression with two denominators

Tags: arithmetic

The task is to simplify the expression: $\displaystyle\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ when $\displaystyle f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$.

I don't know how to do this since I get to the step $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h}$ which gives me two denominators.

Should I multiply each term with $h$ to cancel out the $h$ at the bottom or should I try to multiply so I get the same denominator in the expression $\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}$ ?

Comment: Are you doing Calculus? and having trouble simplifying fractions? If so, you are in for a very, very rough ride.

Comment: No i am not doing Calculus but i am doing an math course in the university and i know this is a basic step one proberly should know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you make sure that you’ve made the correct substitution. This would be
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h = \frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x}{h}\,.
$$
There are many ways of handling this, but I recommend scanning the whole expression and multiplying top and bottom of *the big fraction* by something that removes the fractional nature of the top and the bottom both. In this case, multiply both by $x(x+h)$, and don’t forget to distribute correctly. When you do the multiplication, you get
$$
\frac{x-(x+h)}{x(x+h)h}\,.
$$
Now collapse and simplify.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x+h)-f(x) / h$ when $f(x) = 1/x$ should become 
 $$\Bigg(\frac{1}{(x+h)} - \frac{1}{x}\Bigg) \frac{1}{h}  = \Bigg( \frac{x-x-h}{x(x+h)}\Bigg) \frac{1}{h}$$

You can go on from here and simplify more.

Comment: I like this. Plus one point for you.

Comment: no problem, 2 answers are better than 1. :)